# После input не работает if ,просто игнорируется и завершается код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

При вводе команды `input` не работает `if` 
точнее его пропускает и завершается код без ошибок и причин
про то.

Что надо писать `int(input())` я знаю.
Проверил, что всё работает и там число написав принт перед `input`, но всё мимо.\

**main.py**

```
x = int(input());
if x > 5
  print ('больше')
elif x < 5
  print ('меньше')
```

Comment: Не надо из головы. Приведите **реальный** код, не забудьте про форматирование.

Comment: Всё работает (когда поставить пропущенные двоеточия).

Comment: Впредь: if ВСЕГДА работает. Если вам вдруг кажется, что не работает, то проверяйте свои условия, в них ошибка.

Comment: Если код именно такой, то у вас он просто упадёт из-за ошибок, потому что в конце строк с `if` и `elif` нужны двоеточия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ты пропустил `:`
после `if` и `elif`.

И убери кавычки `;`.

Вот исправленный код:

```
x = int(input("Введите число"))
if x > 5:
  print ('больше')
elif x < 5:
  print ('меньше')
```

Comment: `;` ни на что не влияет в данном случае

Comment: `;` - не кавычки, это *точка с запятой* )

Comment: Извините за мою оговорку на счет ;
конечно в данном случае не влияет.
Да, в Python разрешено использовать точку с запятой ; 
В большинстве случаев использование точки с запятой является необязательным в Python,и используется на усмотрение программиста.
Вот некоторые случаи,когда она тебе может понадобиться:
для разделения операторов в выражении или  для разделение аргументов в функции

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Долгое время не мог понять в чем проблема и поэтому решил задать вопрос:) Хорошего дня.

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть две возможности сделать это правильно:

```
x = int(input('Введите число:'))
print(f'Вы ввели число = {x}') 
  
if x > 5: 
    print(f'{x} больше 5') 
elif x < 5: 
    print(f'{x} меньше 5')
    
print() 

print(f'{x} больше 5') if x > 5 else (print(f'{x} меньше 5\n') if x < 5 else print(f'{x} меньше 5\n'))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]